# ios xcuitest: open app switch not by swiping up or double tap home

Tags: ios, xcuitest

By swiping up to open app switch is quite slow

```
  FBApplication *app = [[FBApplication alloc] initWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.springboard"];
  CGRect frame = app.wdFrame;
  CGSize screenSize = FBAdjustDimensionsForApplication(frame.size, app.interfaceOrientation);
  double toY = screenSize.height*0.001;
  double fromY = screenSize.height*0.999;
  double X = screenSize.width*0.5;
  CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake((CGFloat)X, (CGFloat)fromY);
  CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake((CGFloat)X, (CGFloat)toY);
  NSTimeInterval duration = 0;
  XCUICoordinate *endCoordinate = [self.class gestureCoordinateWithCoordinate:endPoint
                                                                  application:app];
  XCUICoordinate *startCoordinate = [self.class gestureCoordinateWithCoordinate:startPoint
                                                                    application:app];
  [startCoordinate pressForDuration:duration thenDragToCoordinate:endCoordinate];
```

I wonder if there is an API that can be called directly to open the app switch?

open the app switch directly